# Use possibly invalid pointer in ACSL dependencies

Tags: frama-c

I need to write an ACSL specification for the dependencies of a function that takes a pointer as input, and uses its content when the pointer in not NULL.
I think that this specification is correct:

```
/*@ behavior p_null:
      assumes p == \null;
      assigns \result from \nothing;
    behavior p_not_null:
      assumes p != \null;
      assigns \result from *p;
*/
int f (int * p);
```

but I would rather avoid the behaviors, but I don't know if this is correct (and equivalent) :

```
//@ assigns \result from p, *p;
int f (int * p);
```

Can I use `*p` in the right part of the `\from` even if `p` might be `NULL` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. the right part of the `from` indicates which locations **might** contribute to the value of `\result`, but `f` does not need to read from `*p` to compute `\result` (and it should better avoid it if `p` is `NULL` of course).
As a side note, the question could have also been raised for the `assigns` clause of the `p_not_null` behavior, as `p!=\null` does
not imply `\valid(p)` in C.

Nevertheless, the contract without behavior is slightly less precise than the one with behaviors, which states that when `p` is `NULL` a constant value is returned, and when `p` is not null, only the content of `*p` is used (the `assigns` clause without behavior allows to return e.g. `*p+(int)p`, or even `(int)p`).

Comment: I agree that I should have added a 'requires' property stating that 'p!=\null => \valid(p)', but I am only interested in the 'assigns' properties here. Thanks.